# ssh dynamic socks server running in the system is not accessible from outside

Tags: ssh, android

I have an infrastructure hotspot setup on my Ubuntu machine using [ap-hotspot](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html). I connect to this hotspot from my Android phone and am able to access the internet through this.

Now, I have a ssh dynamic SOCKS server running on my Ubuntu machine. Locally, in the Ubuntu machine, I am able to set this as the proxy server in Firefox and am able to connect to the Internet through the remote machine.

I wanted to connect to this SOCKS server from my android as a proxy server. 
The IP address of my Ubuntu machine is 192.168.xxx.xxx and the dynamic SOCKS server was running on port yyyy.

So, in Firefox for android, I set the socks proxy server as 192.168.xxx.xxx and socks proxy port yyyy. But, when I try to load any page, Firefox for Android just says that the Proxy server is not reachable.

To make sure that the port is not blocked, I started up a simple python HTTP server on the same port yyyy and this was accessible from the Android phone. Now I am at a loss at what else to do. Can someone explain, where I am going wrong here?